# How do I add an icon to my RubyMotion Android app?

Tags: android, icons, rubymotion

I'm working on a RubyMotion app for Android. I'd like to add an icon to it. [The documentation](http://www.rubymotion.com/developers/guides/manuals/android/project-management/) says this:

> `icon`: Project icon name, as a String. The value must be the basename (without the extension) of an icon file that exists inside the drawable resource directory

I put this line in my Rakefile:

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  ...
  app.icon = 'icon'
```

I've tried a few places to put the icon file, and haven't been able to get it working:

Placing the icon in `resources/icon.png` gives this error:

```
» rake device
    Create ./build/Development-23/AndroidManifest.xml
invalid resource directory name: ./resources icon.png
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): ["/Users/me/.rubymotion-android/sd...]
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/android.rb:188:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/android.rb:786:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/android.rb:786:in `each'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/android.rb:786:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rm-android/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rm-android/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Placing the icon in `resources/@drawable/icon.png` gives the same error, with `invalid resource directory name: ./resources @drawable`. Placing the icon in the root of the project gives the same error.

Where do I put my icon?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try...

Create a 180x180 PNG file named *icon.png*, and save it in the resources folder.

Now add the following to your rakefile:

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.icons = ['icon.png']
  app.prerendered_icon = true
```